# Show always x rows (datatables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables.net.

For example if you want to show  always 20 rows, 5 rows are real data and the other 15 should be empty(some kind of placeholder).

I am not looking for(those kind of row-length):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 50
} );
```

Is there a way to show always x rows ,without big effort ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code similar to the one below and adjust `row.add()` call based on your table structure.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'initComplete': function(settings){
      var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
      var info = api.page.info();

      for(var i = info.recordsTotal; i < 20; i++){             
         api.row.add(['&nbsp;', '', '', '', '', '']);
      }          

      api.draw(false);
   },
   'order': [1, 'desc'],
   'searching': false,
   'lengthChange': false,
   'pageLength': 20
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/9sfen37y/1/) for code and demonstration.